# Override WP Class Private Function

Tags: plugins, oop

I'm new to community, I think you experts can help me in this.
I have plugin installed and i want to its overwrite one function which is in class

```
    <?php 

 class wf_fedex_woocommerce_shipping_admin{

private function wf_user_permission($auto_generate=null){

$current_minute=(integer)date('i');
        if(!empty($auto_generate) && ($auto_generate==md5($current_minute) || $auto_generate==md5($current_minute+1) ))
        {
            return true;
        }
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
        $user_ok = false;
        $wf_roles = apply_filters( 'wf_user_permission_roles', array('administrator', 'shop_manager') );

        if ($current_user instanceof WP_User) {
            $role_ok = array_intersect($wf_roles, $current_user->roles);
            if( !empty( $role_ok ) ){
                $user_ok = true;
            }
        }
        return $user_ok;
}
}
?>
```

I want to rewrite if so WP will use my custom instead of plugin 
I need a single change in new function ( I mean i just need pass 'subscriber' in array )

```
$wf_roles = apply_filters( 'wf_user_permission_roles', array('administrator', 'shop_manager', 'subscriber') );
```

Comment: See [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/filters/) for the proper way to use filters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @jacob suggest, you can add `subscriber` role into that array using `add_filter` . add below code in active theme's functions.php file.

```
add_filter( 'wf_user_permission_roles', 'wf_user_permission_roles_callback' ) ;
function wf_user_permission_roles_callback( $roles ) {
    $roles[] = 'subscriber';
    return $roles;
}
```

Comment: Thank-you Chetan  :)